# Loading image data from .h5 file showing unusual color in Python 3.5 and h5py

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-compression, h5py

I am using .h5 file to store lot of image data. Then resizing the image and store them in it.

creating dataset for image:
`t1=hdf5_file.create_dataset("train_img", train_shape, np.int8)`

Loop over image address to resize and store them:

```
for i in range(len(train_addrs)):
    addr = train_addrs[i]
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (128, 128), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#save
    hdf5_file["train_img"][i, ...] = img[None]

hdf5_file.close()
```

When I try to check how the image looks with the following code:

```
hdf5_path = 'dataset.hdf5'
train_dataset = h5py.File(hdf5_path, "r")
train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_img"][:])
plt.imshow(train_set_x_orig[5]) #see 5th image
plt.show()
```

I get this unusual image. Top one from .h5 file, Bottom one is original image. I have checked shape of everything, they are fine. `resize` code in `cv2` is also OK. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

[image: After loading image from .h5 file]

[image: Original image]

Comment: What's the dtype(s)?  `img` before saving displays ok?  Is this `[i, ...]` save inside or outside the `i` loop?

Comment: it seems, .h5 file is using 7 bit representation by default.

Comment: dtype used in `create_datset` is `np.int8` . I checked the `resize` part individually. That part is ok. `[i,...]` inside `i` loop. changed that. Any idea how to get it right? @hpaulj

Comment: how to change that 7 bit representation? @Ishant Mrinal

Comment: `dtype=np.uint8`

Comment: Alright. I will change it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I load a b/w png with `scipy.misc`

```
In [1354]: arr2 = misc.imread('../Desktop/newworld2.png')
In [1355]: arr2.shape
Out[1355]: (500, 778, 3)
In [1356]: arr2.dtype
Out[1356]: dtype('uint8')
```

saving it with

```
In [1343]: d2 =f.create_dataset('newworld set',shape=(2, *arr2.shape), dtype=np.uint8)
In [1344]: d2[0]=arr2
In [1345]: d2[1]=arr2
```

preserved the original

saving as `int8` produced the kind of color change that you show

```
In [1348]: d3 =f.create_dataset('newworldbad',shape=(2, *arr2.shape), dtype=np.int8)
In [1349]: d3[0]=arr2
In [1350]: d3[0]
```

white pixels, `[255, 255, 255]` changed to grey `[127, 127, 127]`, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happened!